# How to remove personal information from archive.org?

Tags: archive.org

I found that my personal information was available on some sites. I managed to remove it from them but the information is on `archive.org`. I want to remove cached page on `archive.org` as well.

I have read information on page http://www2.sims.berkeley.edu/research/conferences/aps/removal-policy.html about policy.
This is redirects from the page http://archive.org/about/exclude.php.

I have sent a request to `info@archive.org` but not received any feedback.

What should I do to have my data removed from `archive.org`?

Comment: Give them some time to process your request! When did you sent it?

Comment: First time I have sent them request more than a month ago. It seems enough time. Or no?

Comment: I'm afraid it is... And I guess they are legally obliged to remove your personal data. I don't know how to proceed, anyway good luck sergtk!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have a similar issue and have not received a follow-up.

Comment: no, I didn't try anymore